# Are all the minimal spanning trees can be generated by Kruskal's algorithm?

Tags: graph-theory

Since everyone knows that we can use Kruskal's algorithm to obtain a minimal spanning tree.

I wonder if there is an example about a minimal spanning tree which can not be obtained by the Kruskal's algorithm.